# Determine the exponential generating function $A$ and deduce an expression for $a_n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Let $a_n$ satisfy the recursion $a_n + na_{n−1} = n!$  $\forall$ $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ ∪ {0}. Determine the exponential generating function $A$ and deduce an expression for $a_n$.

So we start with $a_n = -na_{n−1} + n!$ and the fact that $A(n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Then, $A(n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-na_{n-1} + n!) \frac{x^n}{n!}$

gives $A(n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty -na_{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n!} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n $

However, I am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: try $a_n x^n/ (n+1)!$ for $A(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty -na_{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n!} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$$$ =\sum_{n=0}^\infty -a_{n} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n!} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$ by changing $n$ to $n+1$ in the first sum (after noting that $\frac  n {n!}=\frac 1 {(n-1)!}$).

This gives $A(x)=-xA(x)+\frac 1 {1-x}$ for $|x|<1$. Hence, $A(x)=\frac 1 {1-x^{2}}$.